# How to get MethodInfo of interface, if i have MethodInfo of inherited class type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methodinfo

I have the `MethodInfo` of a method on a class type that is part of an interface definition that that class implements.
How can I retrieve the matching `MethodInfo` object of the method on the interface type that the class implements ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i found the best way to do this :

```
var methodParameterTypes = classMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
MethodInfo interfaceMethodInfo = interfaceType.GetMethod(classMethod.Name, methodParameterTypes);
```

Comment: This assumes that the interface method is mapped to a type of the same name. I don't believe it will work if the method is implemented explicitly.

Comment: Typo. I meant: "This assumes that the interface method is mapped to a *class method* of the same name."

Answer (score 3):

Looking up by name and parameters will fail for explicitly implemented interface methods. This code should handle that situation as well:

```
private static MethodInfo GetInterfaceMethod(Type implementingClass, Type implementedInterface, MethodInfo classMethod)
{
    var map = implementingClass.GetInterfaceMap(implementedInterface);
    var index = Array.IndexOf(map.TargetMethods, classMethod);
    return map.InterfaceMethods[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the Method from the interface that the class implements, something like this should work

```
MethodInfo interfaceMethod = typeof(MyClass).GetInterfaces()
                .Where(i => i.GetMethod("MethodName") != null)
                .Select(m => m.GetMethod("MethodName")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if you want to get the method from the interface that the class implements from the method info from the class, you can do.

```
    MethodInfo classMethod = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod");

    MethodInfo interfaceMethod = classMethod.DeclaringType.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(i => i.GetMethod("MyMethod") != null)
        .Select(m => m.GetMethod("MyMethod")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think there might be a problem with this solution, since you might have multiple overloads to the method that have the same `Name`

Comment: you could and any other requirments in the `where` clause,

Comment: I think i already added a more elegant solution. But thanks for the help! :)